# Number of ways to choose elements from array if the sum of the group is at least K

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit

Problem: if we have give integer N, K and array of size N, such that 1 <= N <= 36,
and every integer in the array is <=10^13. Now we have to count on how many different ways we can take elements from array such that the sum of those elements will be at least K

Here is one example: N = 4, K=6, array = {1,2,5,4}
The answer is 9, because we can take elements from the array on nine different ways and their sum will be at least K, the answers are the elements (first and third); (second and third); (first, second and third); (second and fourth); (first, second and fourth); (first, third and fourth); (second, third and fourth); (first, second, third and fourth); (third and fourth).

My idea is with bit-masks we can search over all combinations and choose should we take or shouldn't we, but that has complexity of O(2^N) and in our case N <=36 Which is too slow.

Comment: If any element or combination of elements are greater than K, then adding any elements will still be greater than K, assuming all elements are positive. In your example, if you find that the first and third elements meet the criteria, then automatically you get the sets (1st,2nd,3rd), (1st,3rd,4th),(1st, 2nd,3rd,4th)

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, you can use a 'meet in the middle trick' similar to the one that is usually used to solve the subset sum problem in time `O(N*2^(N/2))` (and you will have the same complexity).

First, compute the `2^N/2` possible sums of the first `N/2` elements, and store them. Do the same with the last `N/2` elements.

Now sort both sets in increasing order. Sorting `n` elements takes time `O(n log n)`, so here that is a `O(N 2^(N/2))` cost. Let's call those 2 sorted sets `F` and `L` (for First and Last).

Then, do the following :

> Set res = 0
>
> for i from 0 to 2^(N/2)-1{
>
> > find the minimum j_i in {0,..,2^(N/2)-1} such that F[i] + L[j_i] >= K (use dichotomic search for this)
> >
> > if such a j_i exists, increase res by (2^(N/2) - j_i)
>
> }
>
> return res

The idea is that for each subset of the first `N/2` elements, you look at how many ways there are to choose a subset of the last `N/2` elements such that the total sum is above `K`. For this, you just have to find the lowest value that achieves this in the sums of the subsets of the last elements, and then you know that the subsets that sum to a value at least as big are exactly the subsets that combine with the initial subset in a sum greater than or equal to `K`, and counting those is easy since you sorted the array of possible values.

P.S : a marginal optimisation is possible by using the fact that the sequence of minimal `j_i` such that `F[i] + L[j_i] >= K` is a non-increasing sequence.